# How to filter posts by category in nuxt/vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to show the posts by selecting categories. I got stuck in filtering the posts by category. I want to use radio buttons to filter them out. I searched on similar solutions about my issue but i couldn't apply them to my case. I tried v-model directive with computed filter functions, but i got undefined posts error. I'm fairly new on Nuxt/VueJs so i really hope someone can give me any advice how to do this. Thanks a lot!

Here is the code i have used:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div id="list" class="container mt-4 ">
            <div class="flex flex-row items-center justify-center">
                <input type="radio"> All
                <div class="ml-2" v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
                    <input type="radio" >
                    <label class="ml-2"> {{post.category}} </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flex flex-col items-center" v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
                <h1 class="text-4xl"> {{ post.title }} </h1>
                <h2 class="text-xl"> {{ post.preText }} </h2>
                <h3 class="text-xs"> {{ post.text }} </h3>
                <h4 class="text-sm"> {{ post.category }} </h4>
            </div>
            <div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
const axios = require('axios')
let url = "https://spreadsheet.glitch.me/?key=1KozD-SrBoDE7sa2_5EHPFwbVO3znWa8V8LpNDw_jfZ8"

export default {

    async asyncData() {
        const response = await axios.get(url)
        const posts = response.data;
        const categories = posts.map(({
            category
        }) => category);

        return {
            posts,
            categories,       

        }

    },   

};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really a Nuxt issue, but how you treat async requests.

You can see a snippet below, that handles async requests and shows the filter you mentioned:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    posts: [],
    filteredPosts: []
  },
  computed: {
    catFilter() {
      return Array.from(new Set(this.posts.map(e => e.category)))
    }
  },
  methods: {
    filterPosts(event) {
      if (event === '') {
        this.filteredPosts = this.posts
      } else {
        this.filteredPosts = this.posts.filter(e => {
          return e.category === event.target.value
        })
      }
    },
    fetchPosts() {
      // return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/')
      return fetch('https://spreadsheet.glitch.me/?key=1KozD-SrBoDE7sa2_5EHPFwbVO3znWa8V8LpNDw_jfZ8')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
          // console.log(json)
          return json
        })
    }
  },
  async mounted() {
    this.posts = await this.fetchPosts()
    this.filteredPosts = this.posts
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h1>Post roll:</h1>
  <div>
    <button @click="filterPosts('')">RESET</button>
    <label v-for="filter in catFilter" :for="filter">{{filter}}
    <input :id="filter" type="radio" name="catfilter" :value="filter" @change="filterPosts($event)"/>
    </label>
  </div>
  <ol>
    <li :key="post.id" v-for="post in filteredPosts">
      <h3>{{post.title}}</h3>
      <div>{{post.preText}}</div><br />
      <div>{{post.text}}</div><br />
      <div>{{post.category}}</div><br />
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    posts: [],
    filteredPosts: []
  },
  computed: {
    catFilter() {
      return Array.from(new Set(this.posts.map(e => e.category)))
    }
  },
  methods: {
    filterPosts(event) {
      if (event === '') {
        this.filteredPosts = this.posts
      } else {
        this.filteredPosts = this.posts.filter(e => {
          return e.category === event.target.value
        })
      }
    },
    fetchPosts() {
      // return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/')
      return fetch('https://spreadsheet.glitch.me/?key=1KozD-SrBoDE7sa2_5EHPFwbVO3znWa8V8LpNDw_jfZ8')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
          // console.log(json)
          return json
        })
    }
  },
  async mounted() {
    this.posts = await this.fetchPosts()
    this.filteredPosts = this.posts
  }
})
```

Comment: This in an exact copy of the first part of Ikolos' answer.